# .htaccess rewrite will accept a number but not a word

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've got a really strange problem that I can't find the answer to.

I've got the following redirect rule set up

```
RewriteRule dog-parks/dog_park/([^/]*) /index?pagename=dog-parks/dog_park&title=$1 [L]
```

It works when I put a number after `dog-parks/dog_park/` as in `dog-parks/dog_park/12/` but when I put a word instead like `dog-parks/dog_park/word`, it's not recognised and the query params does not come through.

Any idea why? Please help.

PS: I'm using Wordpress (if that helps anyone)

Comment: did you try changing **Permalinks Setting** from backend **Dashboard** ? change permalink setting to **post-name**

Comment: Yes. Permalinks are set to post-name

Comment: are you using custom `.htaccess` for permalink ? Why not default wordPress `.htaccess` ? Just curious .

Comment: I've essentially created 'custom posts' without using Wordpress's custom post api